# Read Data From Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read specific data from firebase database. What I am currently doing is here.

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.child("profiles/");

myRef.child(phoneNo).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}

});
```

[image]

Method to write to DB

```
public void writeToDBProfiles(Object data,String phoneNo) {
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.child("profiles/" + phoneNo);
    myRef.setValue(data);
}
```

But its returning null... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have read permission to the data? See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/22652/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-android#t=201609302251033886091

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the snap shot which he shares has the **default security rules banner on top** doesn't that mean that **his .write and .read are both auth != null ?** In that case if he can write then he should be able to read too as the user is authorised isn't it? Please do correct me if am wrong.

Comment: I missed that banner, but indeed it should. The most likely problem is that the user isn't authenticated. Something that you can most easily spot if you add a simple `throw databaseError.toException()` to the `onCancelled()` and a completion listener to the `setValue()`. Both are documented on the page I linked.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have permission.

Comment: OK. This is starting to feel a bit like interactive debugging, for which StackOverflow is ill-suited. Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value instead of `phoneNo`? Can you reproduce it with a `User ` class that has just a single property? Can you share that minimal class? Also humor me and just put error handling code in `onCancelled()` and in your call to `setValue()`.

Comment: Sure, I will get back to android studio and update you on it. Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I wanted to ask one important thing does firebase database supports that my object has a URI element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got it sorted out. the above code in the question is perfectly fine and should work . 
I am explaining for later users who might have the same issue due to mistakes which I made.

the  singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class);  was unable to cast the result to user class because when uploading the data i.e. in setValue I had my 
photoUrl equal to null and as a result you can see the photoUrl is not present in my child node. So what I believe is (and maybe someone want correct me on this) that my singleSnapshot.getValue method was unable to cast the result.

So for now I have omitted photoUrl from my User class and will get back to it when I will start working withe relevant module.

Thanks again everyone for all the suggestions and help.

```
public class User {
String name;
Uri photoURL;
String bloodGroup;
String city;
String country;
double latitude;
double longitude;
boolean availableToDonate;

// Get, set and constructors are obvious here I am just saving some space in the post
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you want to get a specific data using a phone number then you can use a Query like this

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = database.child("profiles");

Query phoneQuery = ref.orderByChild(phoneNo).equalTo("+923336091371");
phoneQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           user = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class); 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

I think this is the best method.

Comment: addListenerForSingleValueEvent gets called only when there is an update to the data. But what if i want to just read the data even when there is no change in the existing data???

I have one requirement where i just need to read some values from a key but with Listeners i'm not able to read it when there are no updates happening.

Comment: Exactly. Bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

*The error in your updated code is here.*

```
myRef.setValue(data);
```

If you are going to add data as myRef.setValue(data) then **you need to specify exactly which child** is getting the data or **if you want to update all children** at once **then you need to do Atomic data update using HashMap() and updateChildren() method.**

So for specific child update the correct way is this:

```
myRef.child("name").setValue(data);
```

I encourage you to read this [official firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) to understand how to update all children in one go **using HashMap()**.

Do let me know if it changes anything for you.

Comment: I just updated the question with how I am writing to the DB. Actually / tells that node is inside profiles node.

Comment: What is your data? .. Are you updating all children or something specific?

Comment: While on the update part I update specific childs using setValue.

Comment: But the issue is I am unable to query specific data from the firebase.

Comment: @MuhammadHassanNiazi check the updated answer if will solve the issue.for specific updates to a child.

Comment: @MuhammadHassanNiazi Do read the blog link I just added in answer.

Comment: @NishatDubey   The issue is not writing to Database or updating it. Thats working fine. The problem is that I am unable to read back data using addListenerForSingleValueEvent. It simply returns null.

Answer (score 0):

while giving location of database of ur firebase, u should always use that folder name in inverted commas, use 
DatabaseReference myRef = database.child("profiles");

instead of
DatabaseReference myRef = database.child("profiles/");