# How to generate CSV/ Excel file from Firebase with Android code

Tags: android, firebase, csv, cart

I have shopping cart in my android App. I am using Firebase as database. I want to mail cart items as CSV / Excel file as attachment.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fetch all data from firebase.

[Read Data From Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800547/read-data-from-firebase-database)

Then you have to generate csv file from the data.

[How to create a .csv on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341931/how-to-create-a-csv-on-android)

After that you can send csv file from its path as an attachment to mail

[How to send an email with a file attachment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974987/how-to-send-an-email-with-a-file-attachment-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

first install excel4node package in your firebase project, then import this in your index.js

```
const xl = require('excel4node');
```

also import these for file handling

```
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'Excel.xlsx');
const storage = admin.storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket();
```

This is how you return the function should look

```
exports.writeFireToExcel = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {

    // Create a new instance of a Workbook class
    const workbook = new xl.Workbook();
    // Add Worksheets to the workbook
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Visa Work List');

    const ref = firebaseDb.ref('path');

    //firebase functions that return stuff must be done in a transactional way

    //start by getting snap
    return await ref.once('value').then(snapshot =>{

    var style = workbook.createStyle({
        font: {
          bold : true,
        },
      });

    //write workbook
        worksheet.cell(1, 1).string('input').style(style);
        //....write the rest of your excel
        return
        //
    }).then(function (){
        console.log('workbook filled');
        //second part of transation - write the excel file to the temp storage in firebase
        //workbook.write doesnt return a promise so ive turned it into a promise function
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
            workbook.write(tempFilePath, function (err, stats) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject(err)
                }else{
                    resolve()
                }
            });
        })
    }).then(function(){
        console.log("File written to: " + tempFilePath);
        //read the file and check it exists
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
            fs.readFile(tempFilePath, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }else{
                    resolve()
                }
            })

        })

    }).then(function(){
        console.log("writing to bucket");
        //write the file to path in firebase storage 
        var fileName = 'VisaSummaryList.xlsx';
        var folderPath = uid + "/excelFile/";
        var filePathString = folderPath + fileName;

        return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, 
            { destination: filePathString}).then(function(){
                return filePathString;
            })

    }).catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
});
```

the function returns a filepath in the firebase storage. In your android app just:

```
 //firebase storage reference, result being whats returned from the firebase function
 val fbstore = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(result)
 fbstore.getFile(myFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.2'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2'
```

Then, create a data class like this:

```
data class Readings(
val temp: String,
val hum: String,
val press: String,
val alt: String,
val timestamp: String
)
```

After that, add a function, similar to the following:

```
fun export2Excel() {
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid

if (uid != null) {
    val firebaseData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserData").child(uid).child("readings")

    firebaseData.keepSynced(true)
    firebaseData.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val list = mutableListOf<Readings>()
            snapshot.children.forEach { timestampSnapshot ->
                val temp = timestampSnapshot.child("temperature").value.toString()
                val hum = timestampSnapshot.child("humidity").value.toString()
                val press = timestampSnapshot.child("pressure").value.toString()
                val alt = timestampSnapshot.child("altitude").value.toString()
                val timestamp = timestampSnapshot.child("timestamp").value.toString()

                list.add(Readings(temp, hum, press, alt, timestamp))
            }

            val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "data.xls")
            val workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file)
            val sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1", 0)

            list.forEachIndexed { index, reading ->
                val timestampDate = Date(reading.timestamp.toLong() * 1000)
                val formattedTimestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(timestampDate)
                val indexLabel = (index + 1).toString()

                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(0, 0, ""))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(1, 0, "Timestamp"))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(2, 0, "Temperature (°C)"))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(3, 0, "Humidity (%Rh)"))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(4, 0, "Pressure (hPa)"))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(5, 0, "Altitude (m)"))

                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(0, index + 1, indexLabel))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(1, index + 1, formattedTimestamp))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(2, index + 1, reading.temp))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(3, index + 1, reading.hum))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(4, index + 1, reading.press))
                sheet.addCell(jxl.write.Label(5, index + 1, reading.alt))
            }

            workbook.write()
            workbook.close()

            Log.d("FB2ExcelViewModel", "Items: $list")
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
    })
  }
}
```

The example given is from my project, and it works 100%.
Please, fill free to modify it according to your own needs.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**